# Como tratar valores que vem no this.props em React

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho um componente Semaforo que chama o componente Luz 3 vezes cada um com seu parâmetro

```
<div className="compSemaforo">
    <Luz color="red" />
    <Luz color="yellow" />
    <Luz color="green" />
</div>
```

como posso na raiz do componente Luz identificar qual é o valor de classe e adicionar uma classe especifica para cada uma das chamadas?

Ressalto que sempre os 3 componentes `<Luz />` serão renderizados cada um com uma classe especifica que alterará seu `background` e já tentei usar `map` e não deu certo

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que você está tentando fazer. O que é essa classe que você está mencionando? A propriedade `color` seria essa classe? E por que você está usando o método `map` para gerar um JSX estático?

Comment: Tem como você exemplificar com o seu código, e porque precisa identificar? tem algum processo que deseja fazer? Talvez o componente Luz só precise mudar a cor (eu to quase entendendo)?

Comment: estou fazendo um sefamofo onde tem a class Semaforo que é essa que coloquei acima e essa class chama o component Luz que é apenas um componente chamado 3 vezes para representar cada cor do semaforo estou passando color="red" para está identificando qual será a sua cor com isso estou tentando receber esse valor no componete Luz e assim efetuar o tratamento para adicionar a cor certa como background do elemento

Comment: Mostre o seu código e você quer ficar trocando de cor?

Comment: Por favor, adicione o codigo do seu componente Luz, para ficar mais claro qual é o problema!

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do seu componente Luz, voce pode usar o atributo className para adicionar a classe desejada, como abaixo:

```
const Luz = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="compLuz {props.color}">
        ...
      </div>
    );
}
```

E entao definir as cores pelo CSS:

```
.compLuz.red { background-color: red; }
.compLuz.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.compLuz.green { background-color: green; }
```